# Using pydoc on modules with imported functions

Tags: python, import, module, pydoc

I have created my own module `X`. At the beginning, I import functions from some other modules (e.g. `from math import func`). I have noticed that when I create documentation with:

```
pydoc -w X
```

the resulting file also contains the imported function function from the `math` module, which is undesirable (especially if I import many functions from several modules, which is what I do).

It can be avoided by instead calling:

```
import math
```

but in this case I have to import all the functions and then call them using `math.func` instead of just `func`.

Is there another way with which I can avoid populating my documentation with imported functions while still being able to import functions with `from`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking inside the source for [`Pydoc`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/pydoc.py#l197) you can see the following comment made:

```
if all is not None:
     # only document that which the programmer exported in __all__
     return name in all
```

meaning that `pydoc` *will look for the `__all__` module attribute*, and, *if defined, will only document the functions defined in it.*

So, for you module `X`, you can define the functions to be exported in `__all__` by specifying their names. Only those will get documented in the corresponding **Functions** section:

```
__all__ = ['myfunc1', 'myfunc2', ..., 'myfuncN']
```

**Case in point:**

Without `__all__`, the following simple file named `mod.py`:

```
from math import cos

def myfunc():
    """ documentation"""
    pass
```

Generates a `mod.html` file that contains the documentation for the user defined `myfunc()` **and** for the imported built-in function `cos()`:

[image]

By adding `__all__` and specifying the function name(s) you'd want to export inside it:

```
__all__ = ['myfunc']  # visible names
from math import cos

def myfunc():
    """ documentation"""
    pass
```

You'll 'filter out' the `cos()` function and only have documentation for `myfunc()`:

[image]

---

**Note:** `__all__` can contain functions *and* variable names used inside you script. `pydoc` will discriminate between these and segregate them in two different groups:

1. Functions in **Functions**
2. Variables in **Data**.